# Exception Handling in Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm working on a Spring webflux project using reactive streams. I have a usecase as follows and want to know how can it be done in a reactive way.

```
  @RestController
  public class Example {

    @GetMapping("/greet")
    public Mono<String> Test() {
       return Mono.just("Tim")
               .map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
               .map(s -> s.toLowerCase())
               .doOnSuccess(s -> validate(s)) // usecase is to validate here in middle of the pipeline
               .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just("Guest"))
               .map(s -> "Hi, "+s);
    }
   
  public void validate(String s) {
    if(s.length() < 5) {throw new RuntimeException("Name is short");}
  }
 
}
```

I know this is a contrived example, but I have something similar to this. I thought throwing an error will lead to exception on browser screen when the endpoint is hit. But to my surprise it went to `onErrorResume()` and I got `Hi, Guest` as response. I thought when `throw` is used to throw an exception before the reactive pipeline is assembled, it will not use `onErrorResume()`. What am I missing here?

Also coming to question #2, how can I achieve this if I'm using `Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Name is short"))`  instead of `throw new RuntimeException("Name is short")`? Can someone please answer my 2 questions. Suggestions to improve code are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide error stacktrace and try to post your suggestion questions in meta exchange

Comment: just as a side note, when writing functional code you should avoid void functions. The function you have above has 2 outcomes, void or exception. That is not good in a functional world. Something more suitable would be `public boolean hasLength(String s, int length)` end then have a if statemtnt that would throw an exception if the it does not have the length required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought when throw is used to throw an exception before the reactive
> pipeline is assembled, it will not use onErrorResume()

`Mono::doOnSuccess` triggers at **execution time** when the `Mono` completes successfully(pipeline is already assembled).

Note that inside intermediate operators like `doOnNext` or `map` you are free to throw exceptions as Reactor can transform them into proper error signals since at that point a `Mono` is already in progress.

> how can I achieve this if I'm using Mono.error(new
> RuntimeException("Name is short")) instead of throw new
> RuntimeException("Name is short")?

You can replace `doOnSuccess` and `map` with the `handle` operator:

```
 return Mono.just("Tim")
            .handle((name, sink) -> {
                if(name.length() < 5){
                    sink.error(new RuntimeException("Name is short"));
                } else {
                    sink.next(name.toLowerCase());
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

For the #1 question you can add a predicate in `onErrorResume`

```
.onErrorResume(e -> !(e instanceof RuntimeException), ex -> Mono.just("Guest"))
```

so that you can filter on which error you can return a predefined result.

For question #2 you can replace `doOnSuccess` which is a consumer, with `flatMap`  and return `Mono` for`validate` method:

```
    public Mono<String> Test() {
        return Mono.just("Tim")
                .map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
                .map(s -> s.toLowerCase())
                .flatMap(s -> validate(s))
                .onErrorResume(e -> !(e instanceof RuntimeException), ex -> Mono.just("Guest"))
                .map(s -> "Hi, " + s);
    }

    public Mono<String> validate(String s) {
        return (s.length() < 5) ?
                Mono.error(() -> new RuntimeException("Name is short")) :
                Mono.just(s);
    }
```